# How can I use a generic parameter on an abstract method with constraints?

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract-class

Consider this example:

```
interface BaseArgs {
  service: string
}

abstract class BaseClass {
  constructor(name: string, args: BaseArgs) {
    this.setFields(args)
  }

  abstract setFields<T extends BaseArgs>(args: T): void
}

interface ChildArgs extends BaseArgs {
  newField: string
}

class Child extends BaseClass {
  setFields(args: ChildArgs): void {}
}
```

I receive this output from Typescript:

```
Property 'setFields' in type 'Child' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClass'.
  Type '(args: ChildArgs) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends BaseArgs>(args: T) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ChildArgs'.
        Property 'newField' is missing in type 'BaseArgs' but required in type 'ChildArgs'.
```

I do want a constraint on args such that it must extend BaseArgs, however I'd assumed so long as Child's setFields accepted a type that extended BaseArgs the compiler would be happy here. What completely obvious thing am I missing here?

I've tried just T without the constraint (the compiler even suggests I add the constraint with `This type parameter might need an extends ChildArgs constraint.`).

I was hoping that in any subclass extending the abstract base class, that setFields could accept any type so long as it extends BaseArgs.

Comment: The type argument for generic functions/methods is chosen by the *caller*, not the implementer. With your `BaseClass`, any subclass must have a `setClass` method that accepts an argument that matches any `T extends BaseArgs` the caller wants.  But your `Child` doesn't meet that requirement, so there's an error. If you want the implementer to choose you have to move the generic scope to `BaseClass` itself, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WPBpeN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah that does make sense, thank you, certainly more than enough for me to achieve what I'm after now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type arguments for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions and methods are chosen by the *caller* and not the *implementer*.  The implementer can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the type parameter, but the caller is free to choose any type argument which matches that constraint.  (Sometimes the compiler will infer the type argument for the caller, but it is still happening on behalf of the caller.)

Your `BaseClass` instances have an interface like

```
interface BaseClass {
  setFields<T extends BaseArgs>(args: T): void
}
```

which means if I have an instance `i` of `BaseClass` then I can call `i.setFields(arg)` for any `arg` I like as long as it's assignable to `BaseArgs`.  Subclasses must adhere to the typings for their superclasses; for `class Child extends BaseClass {}`, every instance of `Child` must also be an instance of `BaseClass`.  That means `Child`'s `setFields()` method must also allow the caller to pass in any `BaseArgs`-compatible argument they want.

So you cannot do this:

```
class Child extends BaseClass {
  setFields(args: ChildArgs): void { } // error!
}
```

because you're trying to restrict which `args` the caller can pass in.  For generic functions and methods, the caller gets to choose the type arguments and the implementer is restricted.

---

Presumably you don't actually want `setFields` to be generic at all, since you want the implementer to choose the argument type it accepts.  Instead, you want the `BaseClass` *class* to be generic.  Generic *types* (like a generic class, generic interface, or generic type alias) have a different scope for their generic parameters:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseArgs> {
  constructor(name: string, args: T) {
    this.setFields(args)
  }
  abstract setFields(args: T): void
}
```

That's essentially like

```
interface BaseClass<T extends BaseArgs> {
  setFields(args: T): void
}
```

There's no such thing anymore as "an instance of `BaseClass`" without specifying the type argument.  You can only have "an instance of `BaseClass<BaseArgs>`" or "an instance of `BaseClass<SomeOtherArgs>`".  That means a subclass of `BaseClass` can decide to extend not just `BaseClass`, but `BaseClass<T>` for any `T` it likes.  In particular, the following is acceptable:

```
class Child extends BaseClass<ChildArgs> {
  setFields(args: ChildArgs): void { } // okay
}
```

Since an instance `i` of `Child` is an instance of `BaseClass<ChildArgs>`, the only thing `i.setFields()` accepts is a `ChildArgs` argument.  So now the implementer is free to choose the type arguments and the caller is restricted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)